# Simple ATM program with various options

Tags: java, finance

This is not much of a question as more of an practice/experience project and feedback request. First off, this was a project I worked on when I started getting into Java last summer and had an assignment that required us to write a simple ATM application. As I'm looking at the code a year later, and gained a bit more experience, I see where it could have been improved. I'm sure there are going to be quite a bit of suggestions and feedback, but to start it off I'm looking the `do while` loop in the main program, and feel that the logic can be simplified such that the first or even second `if` statements can place outside of the loop as I feel that using all 3 can be redundant.  Perhaps incorporating a boolean true/false statement.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ATM {

    public static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    // The checkID method determines if acctNum is a valid account number
    // and pwd is the correct password for the account.  If the account information
    // is valid, the method returns the current account balance, as a string.
    // If the account information is invalid, the method returns the string "error".
    public static String checkID(String acctNum, String pwd)
    {
        String result = "error";

        // Strings a, b, and c contain the valid account numbers and passwords.
        // For each string, the account number is listed first, followed by
        // a space, followed by the password for the account, followed by a space,
        // followed by the current balance.
        String a = "44567-5 mypassword 520.36";
        String b = "1234567-6 anotherpassword 48.20";
        String c = "4321-0 betterpassword 96.74";

        if (acctNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1,a.lastIndexOf(" "))))
            return result = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        if (acctNum.equals(b.substring(0, b.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(b.substring(b.indexOf(" ")+1,b.lastIndexOf(" "))))
            return result = b.substring(b.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        if (acctNum.equals(c.substring(0, c.indexOf(" "))) && 
                pwd.equals(c.substring(c.indexOf(" ") + 1,c.lastIndexOf(" "))))
            return result = c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);

        return result;
    }

    public static int menu()
    {
        int menuChoice;
        do
        { 
            System.out.print("\nPlease Choose From the Following Options:"
                    + "\n 1. Display Balance \n 2. Deposit"
                    + "\n 3. Withdraw\n 4. Log Out\n\n");

            menuChoice = kbd.nextInt();

            if (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 4){
                System.out.println("error");
            }

        }while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 4);

        return menuChoice;
    }

    public static void displayBalance(double x)
    {
        System.out.printf("\nYour Current Balance is $%.2f\n", x);
    }

    public static double deposit(double x, double y)
    {
        double depositAmt = y, currentBal = x;
        double newBalance = depositAmt + currentBal;

        System.out.printf("Your New Balance is $%.2f\n",  newBalance);

        return newBalance;
    }

    public static double withdraw(double x, double y)
    {
        double withdrawAmt = y, currentBal = x, newBalance;

        newBalance = currentBal - withdrawAmt;
        System.out.printf("Your New Balance is %.2f\n",newBalance);

        return newBalance;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String accNum, pass, origBal = "error";
        int count = 0, menuOption = 0;
        double depositAmt = 0, withdrawAmt = 0, currentBal=0; 
        boolean  foundNonDigit;
        //loop that will count the number of login attempts
        //you make and will exit program if it is more than 3.
        //as long as oriBal equals an error.  
        do{
            foundNonDigit = false;
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Account Number: ");
            accNum = kbd.next();

            System.out.println("Enter Your Password: ");
            pass = kbd.next();

            origBal = checkID(accNum, pass);

            count++;

            if (count >= 3 && origBal.equals("error")){
                System.out.print("Maximum Login Attempts Reached.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if (!(origBal.equals("error"))){
                System.out.println("\nYour New Balance is: $ "+ origBal);
            }
            else
                System.out.println(origBal);


        }while(origBal.equals("error"));

        currentBal=Double.parseDouble(origBal);
        //this loop will keep track of the options that 
        //the user inputs in for the menu. and will 
        //give the option of deposit, withdraw, or logout.

        while (menuOption != 4)
        { 
            menuOption=menu();
            switch (menuOption)
            {
            case 1:
                displayBalance(currentBal);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.print("\nEnter Amount You Wish to Deposit: $ ");
                depositAmt = kbd.nextDouble();
                currentBal=deposit(depositAmt, currentBal);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.print("\nEnter Amount You Wish to Withdrawl: $ ");
                withdrawAmt = kbd.nextDouble();

                while(withdrawAmt>currentBal){
                    System.out.print("ERROR: INSUFFICIENT FUNDS!! "
                            + "PLEASE ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: $");
                    withdrawAmt = kbd.nextDouble();
                }

                currentBal = withdraw(currentBal, withdrawAmt);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.print("\nThank For Using My ATM.  Have a Nice Day.  Good-Bye!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Please Enter Your Account Number: 
> 44567-5
> Enter Your Password: 
> mypassword
>
> Your New Balance is: $ 520.36
>
> Please Choose From the Following Options:
>  1. Display Balance 
>  2. Deposit
>  3. Withdraw
>  4. Log Out
>
> 2
>
> Enter Amount You Wish to Deposit: $ 400
> Your New Balance is $920.36
>
> Please Choose From the Following Options:
>  1. Display Balance 
>  2. Deposit
>  3. Withdraw
>  4. Log Out
>
> 3
>
> Enter Amount You Wish to Withdrawl: $ 1000
> ERROR: INSUFFICIENT FUNDS!! PLEASE ENTER A DIFFERENT AMOUNT: $600
> Your New Balance is 320.36
>
> Please Choose From the Following Options:
>  1. Display Balance 
>  2. Deposit
>  3. Withdraw
>  4. Log Out
>
> 1
>
> Your Current Balance is $320.36
>
> Please Choose From the Following Options:
>  1. Display Balance 
>  2. Deposit
>  3. Withdraw
>  4. Log Out
>
> 4
>
> Thank For Using My ATM.  Have a Nice Day.  Good-Bye!
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Storing passwords

The recommended approach for reading passwords is to use a `char[]` array, instead of a `String`. The main reason for this, as explained in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881376/1144592), is that immutable `String`s leave your passwords accessible until garbage collection (GC) kicks in, with a malicious process performing a memory dump of your Java process to do so.

Helpfully, [`Console.readPassword()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--) returns a `char[]` array while hiding the user input on the console:

```
char[] password = System.console().readPassword();
// validate password
// replace the char[] array contents immediately after validation
Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
```

## Reading data, and data modeling

Currently, you are hardcoding the account details as mere space-delimited `String`s. This is not desirable from a data modeling perspective as it is non-trivial to:

- 'Upgrade' the formatting to support newer or different fields,
- Make edits, and
- Test.

These 'pain points' are evident in the way you are doing validation currently:

```
if (acctNum.equals(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(" "))) && 
        pwd.equals(a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1,a.lastIndexOf(" "))))
    // BTW looks like you have a typo/bug here
    // return result = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
    result = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
```

- You have to manually identify where each column starts and ends.
- The code *assumes* the account number is in the first field, the password is the second, and the result is in third and final field.
- (related to the earlier section, and a big security no-no) Your passwords are in clear text, instead of being encrypted (or at least hashed).
- You have hardcorded three accounts into three different variables, which is not scalable.

**So how can this be done differently?**

Let's start with a class called `Account`:

```
public class Account {
    String name;
    String encryptedPassword;
    double balance;

    public class Account(String name, String encryptedPassword, double balance) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(name);
        this.encryptedPassword = Objects.requireNonNull(encryptedPassword);
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    // create getters and setters too

    public boolean isMatching(String name, String encryptedPassword) {
        return Object.equals(this.name, name) 
                    && Objects.equals(this.encryptedPassword, encryptedPassword);
    }
}
```

With a class-based design, adding new fields or changing their data types is a lot easier. Now, we need a mechanism that knows how to interact with multiple accounts, and perform validation on picking an account. An `AccountManager` sounds like one for the job:

```
public class AccountManager {
    // using a List here for simplicity
    private final List<Account> accounts = getAccounts();

    // no modifiers used as an illustration to show how testing can override this
    List<Account> getAccounts() {
        // read from a source, e.g. database, and return as a List of Account objects
    }

    public Account getAccount(String accountName, char[] password) {
        String encryptedInput = encryptPassword(password);
        Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
        // simple implementation that loops through the accounts
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.isMatching(accountName, encryptedInput)) {
                return account;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The use of a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) lets us store one, three, 10, or more accounts easily without having to deal with a multitude of variables. We also need to encrypt the password first, then rely on the `Account.isMatching()` method that lets us easily identify which account matches on the inputs. In this case, we no longer have to worry how to read space-delimited `String`s in order to identify the account name and password parts correctly.

In order to help with the testing, you can create a `TestAccountManager` that override `getAccounts()` to use some test data:

```
// assuming same package
public class TestAccountManager extends AccountManager {

    @Override
    List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Account("acct1", "...", 1),
                                new Account("acct2", "...", 2),
                                new Account("acct3", "...", 3));
    }

    // ...

}
```

## Variable names

```
public static double deposit(double x, double y)
{
    double depositAmt = y, currentBal = x;
    // ...
}

public static double withdraw(double x, double y)
{
    double withdrawAmt = y, currentBal = x, newBalance;
    // ...
}
```

I thought it is... mildly amusing that you know what the *appropriate* variable names should used as the method parameters, and yet you stuck with `x` and `y` only to perform the assignment afterwards. They should be rewritten as such:

```
public static double deposit(double currentBalance, double depositAmount)
{
    // ...
}

public static double withdraw(double newBalance, double withdrawalAmount)
{
    // ...
}
```

## Reducing code duplication

You have very similar ways of printing the balances in the `displayBalance()`, `deposit()` and `withdrawal()` methods, differing only in the output. This ties in with the use of a suitable model class as explained in the earlier section. For example:

```
public class Account {

    // ...

    public boolean deposit(double amount) {
        // ...
    }

    public boolean withdrawal(double amount) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toString("Current");
    }

    public String toString(String description) {
        return String.format("Your %s Balance is $%.2f", description, balance);
    }
}
```

With these methods, it simplifies how money is deposited or withdrawn from an `Account`, and how the balance can be shown:

```
// show current balance
System.out.println(account);
// do a deposit
boolean isMoneyDeposited = account.deposit(100);
if (isMoneyDeposited) {
    System.out.println(account.toString("New"));
}
```

## `try-with-resources`

If you are on Java 7 and above, you should use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword--) for efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

## Consistent bracing style

If you are more comfortable with orphan/standalone braces on each line, then do so consistently to improve the code readability. :) Your class declaration and the `main()` method deviate from this, and some of your `if-else` statements are also missing braces.

Comment: Great answer, except that when Scanner is opened to System.in, it should never be closed.  If you do, you can never reopen it.